# How can I make sure that my copy[i] doesn't point at the same memory address in C programming language

Tags: c

I am having trouble with arrays in C. How can I make sure that my copy[i] doesn't point at the same memory address? Basically, my charCount variable changes its value and I want to store it in an array. It works but as you can see in the image, it changes the initial value since it points to the same memory address, and that's not what I want. How can I fix this please help!!

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx1Uu.png)

HERE IS MY CODE:
[CODE PART 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsYvw.png)
[CODE PART 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxAFB.png) [CODE PART 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGAOh.png)

Comment: Post the code and the error text in the question, not links to images

Comment: To convert a code image to text:
(1) On your system, select the desired text and copy to your clipboard
(2) Edit your question here on this page
(3) Enter `\`\`\`` on a separate line
(4) Paste your clipboard
(5) Enter `\`\`\`` on a separate line
(6) Save your edit

Comment: Your code doesn't use copy

Comment: Yes it does I forgot to add it! Sorry. but my error is that I can't seem to figure out how to make sure my copy[i] doesn't share the same memory address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood you want to make sure that `copy[i]` has different values of the `charCount` variable for different values of `i`. You can see that at point in your code you have the line:

```
copy[i] = charCount;
```

and you defined `charCount` as

```
char charCount[100] = "";
```

In this context `charCount` is a pointer to a memory location which contains the values that are stored there. Which means when you set `copy[i]` to `charCount` you are setting `copy[i]` value to the pointer value of `charCount` instead of its contents.

Instead of setting `copy[i]` to `charCount` you need to allocate a new 100 bytes every time you set `copy[i]`. You can do this by using a `malloc` statement.

For example, instead of doing

```
sprintf(charCount, "%d", count);

strcat(charCount, "\t");
strcat(charCount, file_name);
strcat(charCount, "\n");

copy[i] = charCount;
```

you could write

```
char * newStr = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
sprintf(newStr, "%d", count);

strcat(newStr, "\t");
strcat(newStr, file_name);
strcat(newStr, "\n");

copy[i] = newStr;
```

I don't know if you are using `charCount` anywhere else but with this method you don't even need it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to fix my issue.